# How do you count number of operations in java code , i'm not sure but can someone verify my work

Tags: java

```
Sum <- 0  // 1 Operation 
for i <- 1 to n do // 2n operations
 for j <-1 to n do // 2(n-1) operations
  k <-1 // 1 operation
while k < n do // n-1 operations
k <- k *c // 2 operations 
sum <- sum +1  // 2 operations
```

In total the number of operations in the code are :

1+2n+2(n-1)+1+(n-1)+2+2 == 5n+3 total # of operations ,

is this how you calculate it , because i understand the concept of each stmt has 3 portions to it ( Comparison, Assignment, Incrementation )

please feel free to correct me is my observations are incorrect

Comment: Are the last two lines supposed to be indented?

Comment: Perhaps you could accept answers to other questions you've asked. Show your love for those of us that hang around here hitting "refresh" looking for questions to answer.

Comment: @duskwuff yes the last two lines are suppose to be indented

Paul : what do you mean by accept answer's , im not looking for answers just some guide lines on counting operations ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's probably incorrect.

First of all: You're thinking too hard. At least for the purposes of Big-O calculations, you can probably treat each assignment as a single operation, no matter whether it's a constant assignment or a calculated value.

Second of all: You aren't thinking hard enough. The fourth line is a single operation, but it's run `n * n` times, so it should be counted as `n^2`, not `1`. Similarly for other lines in loops.

Comment: why would my forth line run n^2 times ? it's a single statement embedded in a loop which iterates : 2(n-1) times ... a little confused lol

Comment: No, it is embedded in a loop (`j`), which is in turn embedded in another loop (`i`). So that makes it n^2 instead of 2n

Comment: alright then after recalculating i get 3n^2+6n-3 for the code listed above , would my answer be correct ?